# Firefox Extensions get current User-Agent

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I know that we are able to change useragent string by setting key `general.browser.useragent.override`

but how can I get current useragent string when it's not available through nsIPrefService ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `userAgent` property on `nsIHttpProtocolHandler` should give this to you.  http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/ddaf5686c70c/services/sync/modules/service.js#l378 shows a typical usage.

That's assuming you're in a JS component.  If you're running in a Window object, just use `navigator.userAgent`.